# Can I remotely control an Android device using TeamViewer?

Tags: teamviewer

I have installed TeamViewer on my PC and mobile. I can operate/remotely control my PC on my mobile, but can I do the opposite and operate/remotely control my Android device from my PC?

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it is possible to remotely control an Android device using TeamViewer, but not all devices are supported yet.

There are a couple of different apps for TeamViewer:

TeamViewer for Remote Control is the app that allows you to remotely control your PC from an Android device.

TeamViewer QuickSupport is the app that is needed to control your Android device from your PC.  It will provide the ID necessary to establish the connection to your device.  This app doesn't work by itself though.  You will also need to install the appropriate QS AddOn pack for your particular device.  If there is not a QS AddOn for your device, then you won't be able to control your Android from your PC with TeamViewer at this time.

Comment: Also there are other apps which work more or less the same. My favorite is Webkey, but VNC servesr for Android also exist. Of course, these need root.

Answer (score -3):

The TeamViewer application for Android is just an Interface to connect to a PC and operate it remotely.

If you observe the Android application screen (TeamViewer), there is only input field where you need enter the remote PC TeamViewerID. But, it will not give you any TeamViewID for your android device.