# How to remotely access an Android device from any device connected to the internet with root access?

Tags: applications, security, remote-control, remote-access

Out of curiosity, I always wondered is it possibly to access your android device remotely, your files, start any app, run any function you will want to the same way you can do as if you were with the device physically. If it is, then how?

I'm kinda thinking if I should have the following;

- IMEI
- ESN
- MEID
- Google Account

It should be more than enough to grant me full access to my device.

Considering the IMEI is can be used to identify the device, ESN (Electronic Serial Numbers) and MEID (Mobile Equipment Identifiers) can link an individual to a phone. And with the Google account used on the device.

Since a remote desktop software lets you access your computer and all its applications over the Internet using another device, essentially by streaming a feed of your desktop. This works from a tablet or phone, even over a cellular data network, I feel an android device should be able to do same.

I have checked to see possible question;

- [I want to remotely control my Android device from my PC without rooting it. Is this possible?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1931/i-want-to-remotely-control-my-android-device-from-my-pc-without-rooting-it-is-t)
- [Remotely control an Android tablet from a Mac or Windows machine?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/58952/remotely-control-an-android-tablet-from-a-mac-or-windows-machine?rq=1)
- [Accessing and Controlling an Android Device Remotely](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/156946/accessing-and-controlling-an-android-device-remotely)
- [Can I remotely control an Android device using TeamViewer?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/86031/can-i-remotely-control-an-android-device-using-teamviewer)
- [is there way to remotely turn on your android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/161059/is-there-way-to-remotely-turn-on-your-android-phone)

but none has fully answered the question.

**NOTE**: This is with the assumption that the android device has access to the internet and throughout the remote access, the device will have access to the internet. There's no restriction to the usage of just TeamViewer.

Any good answer and comment is greatly accepted on if there's an app that can actually do that or what it takes to make such kinda app. Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: "but none has fully answered the question" Could you explain that further? How precisely is your question different from those existing questions?

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/156946/accessing-and-controlling-an-android-device-remotely specified on using a particular app (Teamviewer) and there seems to be a whole lot of improvement in android technology compared to the time those questions where asked.